# How do I use two different fonts in boxes?

Tags: fonts, microsoft-visio-2013

I'm making a simple scheme in Visio 2013, I have to use two different fonts in one box. When I change the font from the box in the control panel, it changes the whole text's font in the box I'm writing in. I've tried to change the font by using the right mouse button and choosing font section, but it didn't help.

How do I use two different fonts in boxes?

Answer (score 1):

Rather than changing the box properties, all you have to do is highlight the text within the box you desire to change.

1. Double click the box to enter edit mode
2. Highlight the text
3. Change it to the font of your liking
4. Click outside the box to save the change

[image]